# NodeSource SSL issue on AWS CodeBuild

Tags: node.js, angular, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have deployed my Angular app using AWS CodeBuild, it was working fine until today morning. All of a sudden the build is failing & throwing this error. I think it has something to do with node.js repo, but not sure how to fix it.

[image]

I've also tried these links:

- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -
- http://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash -

Also here is my build spec:

```
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo installing nodejs...
      - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
      - apt-get install -y nodejs
      - echo installing yarn...
      - curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
      - echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
      - apt install --no-install-recommends yarn
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo installing dependencies...
      - npm i -g @angular/cli
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      # - echo testing...
      # - echo building...
      - ng build --prod
artifacts:
  files:
    - "**/*"
  discard-paths: no
  base-directory: 'dist'
```

Comment: I think it is because the letsEncrypt is not trusted certificate authority and all of its certificate has expired as of sept 30 2021. so this might be the issue, since you are using SSL. try`pkg install node` instead of `curl` and for `yarn` too

Comment: @SachinAnanthakumar is ```pkg``` already available in Ubuntu by default? or is there a different method for installing it first?

Also, I check the deb.nodesource, it says that it'll expire on Dec 7, 2021. So maybe that's not the issue.

Comment: if you are using `ubuntu` the use `apt install node`

Comment: I don't think that allows node 12 or node 14 version with ```apt```. Does it?

Comment: which version do you want? `12.x` ?

Comment: Yes, that would work with my current angular version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237681/discussion-between-muhammad-usman-and-sachin-ananthakumar).